# getURL not finding my custom module controller

Tags: controllers, 404-page, geturl

I am adding in a new mass action for the sales order grid and when I am putting in the url for my action Magento cannot find my controller.

config.xml

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <mymodule>
        <use>admin</use>
        <args>
            <module>Namespace_mymodule</module>
            <frontName>frontendname</frontName>
        </args>
        </mymodule>
    </routers>
</admin>

<global>
    <events>
        <adminhtml_block_html_before>
        <observers>
            <mymodule>
            <class>Namespace_mymodule_Model_Observer</class>
            <method>addActions</method>
            </mymodule>
        </observers>
        </adminhtml_block_html_before>
    </events>
</global>
```

observer.php

```
public function addActions($event)
{
    $block = $event->getBlock();
    if($block instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid)
    {
        $block->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('cpsync', array(
            'label' => 'Push Orders to CounterPoint',
            'url' => Mage::helper("adminhtml")->getUrl("frontendname/adminhtml_index/push/")
        ));
    }
}
```

Whenever I try to use my mass action it sends me to a 404 redirect page with url

sitename.com/index.php/frontendname/adminhtml_index/push/key/

Comment: My Better404 module (free, opens source) can help you track down 404 page related issues. http://alanstorm.com/magento-404-debug

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
if(get_class($block) =='Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Massaction'
        && $block->getRequest()->getControllerName() == 'sales/order')
    {
        $block->addItem('cpsync', array(
            'label' => 'Push Orders to CounterPoint',
            'url' => Mage::app()->getStore()->getUrl('*/yourcontroller/youraction'),
        ));
    }
```

If your controller file's name is something like `CpsyncController.php`, it would need a method like `public function pushAction(){<!--your code here-->}`, the `*/yourcontroller/youraction` bit in your Observer would be `*/cpsync/push`

P.S it is imperative that you use the Action suffix after the method name in your controller for the redirect to pick up the function itself.

Comment: still getting the same url with the 404 redirect. its in a folder called adminhtml in controllers and then IndexController.php would the url be */adminhtml_index/push?